# detecting URL where a particular request is getting processed

Tags: php, wordpress, mod-rewrite, web

I have a POST request that gets processed on the URL `http://<mysite>/login` and I don't have a server side script "login". My web server uses wordpress and the translation is probably dur to mod_rewrite. Is there a way I can get to know which server side script processes my parameters sent to login.

Comment: @BhuvanRikka didnt got you :( .. Something I am missing..I am new to stack overflow relatively

Comment: How do I accept questions or answers?

Comment: @user1466594 He means you have the option of selecting an answer as the one which solved your problem. You haven't done so far with all the 5 questions that you've asked

Comment: @asprin ohhh.. I didnt knew that..I just voted them till now..

Comment: @user1466594 Go back to your previous questions,select the best answer which solved your question and click on the "tick" mark

Comment: @user1466594 - While what the others are saying is correct - remember: You don't *have* to accept an answer. **It is your choice whether or not to accept an answer**, and it is based on whether or not the answer satisfies you.

Comment: @ArjunShankar thanks arjun just did exactly what u said..

Comment: So any answers for my redirection query?